# Angular 2.4 No component factory found. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular

I was following one of the guides around to add dynamic components. 
The only difference I'm seeing with those guides is that I'm launching the dynamic component from a selector (instead of an event like a click event) and also, the angular version (2.4.8 in my case)

Things that I have tried:

- Put the entryComponents inside the DynamicSectionComponent.
- Put the entryComponents inside the HomeModule.
- Put the entryComponents inside    the AppModule.

But I haven't figure out what to do, and I'm starting to think that may be related to the angular version I'm using. Any ideas?

Error:

> caused by: No component factory found for OneColumnSection. Did you
>   add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

**Selector in home.html**

```
 <sr-dynamic-section-component [componentData]="{'component': 'OneColumnSection', 'inputs': {'showNum': 2}}"></sr-dynamic-section-component>
```

**Dynamic Section Component.ts**
I have added some console.logs in there, and they are being log except the one after the factory.

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ViewChild,
  ReflectiveInjector,
  ComponentFactoryResolver
} from "@angular/core";
import {OneColumnSection} from "./one-column.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'sr-dynamic-section-component',
  entryComponents: [OneColumnSection],
  template: `
    <div #dynamicSectionComponentContainer></div>
  `,
})
export class DynamicSectionComponent {

  currentComponent:any = null;

  @ViewChild('dynamicSectionComponentContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) dynamicSectionComponentContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  // component: Class for the component you want to create
  // inputs: An object with key/value pairs mapped to input name/input value
  @Input() set componentData(data: {component: any, inputs: any }) {
    if (!data) {
      return;
    }
    console.log("Component:" + data.component);
    console.log("Inputs:" + JSON.stringify(data.inputs));
    // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
    let inputProviders = Object.keys(data.inputs).map((inputName) => {
      return {provide: inputName, useValue: data.inputs[inputName]};
    });
    let resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve(inputProviders);

    // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(resolvedInputs, this.dynamicSectionComponentContainer.parentInjector);

    console.log("about to factory:");
    // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);
    console.log("factory:" + factory);

    // We create the component using the factory and the injector
    let component:any = factory.create(injector);

    // We insert the component into the dom container
    this.dynamicSectionComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);

    // We can destroy the old component is we like by calling destroy
    if (this.currentComponent) {
      this.currentComponent.destroy();
    }

    this.currentComponent = component;
  }

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }
}
```

**OneColumnSection.ts**

```
import {Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sr-one-column-section',
  template: `
    <div>Hello World One Column{{showNum}}</div>
  `,
})
export class OneColumnSection {
  showNum = 0;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.showNum = this.injector.get('showNum');
  }
}
```

**HomeModule.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home.component";
import {HomeRoutingModule} from "./home-routing.module";
import {DynamicSectionComponent} from "./dynamic-section.component";
import {OneColumnSection} from "./one-column.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [HomeRoutingModule],
  declarations: [HomeComponent,DynamicSectionComponent,OneColumnSection],
  entryComponents: [OneColumnSection],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

**Adding list of files inside the home folder.**

- dynamic-section.component.ts
- home.component.html
- home.component.ts
- home.module.ts
- home-routing.module.ts
- one-column.component.ts

Comment: Can you show the file list in your project? I suspect it is a name issue. See this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10735

Comment: @wannadream, all the files are in the same folder, so I don't have a path to have a typo in there. 
What it was weird when testing, and trying, it was that if I remove the OneColumnSection from the declarations array, the error is that the Component is not declared.

Comment: Can you try to remove entryComponents?
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-when-entry-components

Comment: @wannadream removing the entryComponents doesn't change anything. Same error

Comment: I found out what happen

Answer (score 0):

If I change

```
let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(data.component);
```

by

```
let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(OneColumnSection);
```

That works, so the problem is that the selector is sending OneColumnComponent as a string, and I didn't realize that because I was logging the input and I saw OneColumnSection being passed properly.
I just need to figure out the best way to pass that parameter to the component.

Thanks anyway!